# validation error message for radio buttons using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

am using the code as follows to validate radio buttons. the error message is getting before the radio button i need it after the radio buttons please help me thanks. according to my requirement i need it after the radio buttons

```
rules: {
    state: {
        required: true,
    },
    fiscal_yr: {
        required: true,
    },
    date_biennial_budget: {
        required: true,
    },
    high: {
        required: true,
    }
},
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.attr("type") == "radio") {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
},
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ of your problem? not much clear here. I might be able to help you then.

Comment: You don't see that you are putting your error before the element (`error.insertBefore(element);`) and that there lies the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.attr("type") == "radio") {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
```

with

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

You are catching if it is a radio button and telling the error to position itself before the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if` clause in:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("type") == "radio") {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```

Just need:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {     
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try this:

```
 error.appendTo(element.next());
```

Or

```
 error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
```